# 'Select All Checkboxes' is NOT sending the checkboxes to local storage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Local storage is working well for the id's of individual country selections, but when I click the 'select all' icon I expect ALL country id's to pass to local storage. Unfortunately nothing is passed. Spent hours on this already.  Anyone know how I can get this to work? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4puuhs2x/

```js
// Saving checkboxes to local-storage
$(function() {

  // Save checkbox status to local-storage
  var $containers = $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn');

  $containers.on("change", "input", function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox:checked');
    var selected = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get();
    selected = '#' + selected.join(',#');
    localStorage.setItem('selected_checkboxes', selected);
    console.log('setting selected ids: ', selected);
  });
});


$("#CountrySelectAll_ID_prodn").on('click', function() {
  $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
});

$("#CountrySelectNone_ID_prodn").on('click', function() {
  $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="styleheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" />


<button type='submit' id="SelectALLCountryID_prodn" class="sbButtonIconStyle1">
    <i id="CountrySelectAll_ID_prodn" class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg" 
    title="Select All"></i>
    </button>
<button type='submit' id="SelectNONECountryID_prodn" class="sbButtonIconStyle1">
    <i id="CountrySelectNone_ID_prodn" class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg" 
    title="Unselect All"></i>
    </button>
<hr>

<div id="CountryListBoxID_prodn">
  <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN40" 
    value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN251" 
    value="France" />France</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN276" 
    value="Germany" />Germany</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't too far off.

You just needed to set the localStorage on the select all click

```
localStorage.setItem('selected_checkboxes', '#' + $containers.find("input:checked").map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get().join(',#'))
```

See updated jsFiddle here with a working piece of code: http://jsfiddle.net/4puuhs2x/2/

Comment: A very elegant solution and the only one that works. Much appreciated

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger change event.

Try this

```
$("#CountrySelectAll_ID_prodn").on('click', function()
{ 
   $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked',true);
   $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").trigger('change');
});

$("#CountrySelectNone_ID_prodn").on('click', function()
{ 

  $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked',false);
  $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your id selector was wrong. you need to use button id to select.

```
$("#SelectALLCountryID_prodn").on('click', function()
{ $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked',true);
});

$("#SelectNONECountryID_prodn").on('click', function()
{ $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked',false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4puuhs2x/3/

Comment: Hate to pull an answer up, but if you do a console log on the localStorage after the checked to true, this doesn't work and doesn't set all the selected items into localStorage 
 - console.log(localStorage.getItem('selected_checkboxes'));